# backup of datastore to local machine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups, gcloud

I have some data stored  in the Google Datastore. I have two entities in the Google Datastore for this purpose. I was wondering if there is a way to backup these Datastore entries periodically to my  local machines ? I searched the internet and could some answers related to using task queues, cron jobs, etc but none of them offered a complete, working solution to this problem. It would be great if someone could share their ideas about how to  periodically backup the datastore to local machines.

Thanks and Regards,
Rohith

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to do a backup of your datastore from your admin console, but it's a manual backup.

Using a cron job or a task queue, as you mention, would definitely work in having code do your backup (you have a cron job that reads your whole datastore, then copies it locally to a csv or something).  My concern regarding that would be cost, because reading/copying your whole datastore definitely DOESN'T scale and will end up being quite expensive in fact.

If you need it once a month or once every other month, I would manually do the backup.  I don't know if there's a way to programmatically call that backup function though

Comment: could you point out some reference to the cron job method you told ? I tried setting it up but it seemed to have some problem. thanks.

Comment: If you're in python : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

if you're in java :  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

Answer (score 0):

You can use the managed export and import feature, which can be accessed through gcloud or the Datastore Admin API. You can export data manually or use App Engine to export on a schedule:

[Exporting and Importing Entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities)

[Scheduling an Export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export)